# How to get the Volume of an irregular 3d shape

Tags: education, volume

I am calculating the shear and moment for a combined foundation with bi-axial moments on each columns.
I got the pressure at 4 corners under the foundation.
in order to be able to calculate the sheer and moment, I would like to know how to calculate the volume of pressures under foundation.
pressures look like below photo.

If I will be able to calculate the volume of below prism, then things will be easy.
The top side is NOT planar
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question already seems to have an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438766/volume-of-irregular-solid

Comment: The first thing to do is to decide how your upper surface looks like. As you say, it may not be planar indeed: just imagine a square on the ground, and on three of the four edges, the height is 10. But on the fourth edge the height is 1. There are multiple ways to create a surface, fitting in that, but which one will you choose for simulating your situation?

Comment: @MartinWestin: I believe the question you refer to mentions a situation where the upper part is a plane, which is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks @MartinWestin yes, the upper part is not plan

Comment: @MartinWestin thanks for the link, I am reading the answer of Mark Davich

Comment: You can find the answer in reply of Mark davish https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438766/volume-of-irregular-solid thanks to @MartinWestin for posting the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as noted in the comments, it already has an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438766/volume-of-irregular-solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top is not planar, then the best we can do without a decent bit more of information is estimate.  As is noted by Martin Westin, this has been answered already.

But to quickly summarize, we basically just average the heights: $h = \frac{h_1+h_2+h_3+h_4}{4}$ and use that as the height of a box.  So the volume is: $$V = a\cdot b\cdot h$$  It is a rather good estimate if the top is close to planar.  And without doing lots of measuring, I doubt you will be able to get closer to the real value.

Comment: The top part might not be close to the planar. Its all depend on the forces and moment applied to the pedestals. I cannot use an average otherwise the result will not be accurate.

Comment: your answer is correct, even if it is planar, the volume will be as you said, can anyone confirm before accepting the answer please?

Comment: @XinLok It is the same answer as worked out in detail in the linked post by Martin Westin.  Look there for the full explanation.

Comment: Full explanation is available in the linked posted by Martin